# Trusty GHC from universe breaks Trusty

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to install [haskell compiler GHC](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ghc), and some other packages dependent on it. (version 6.4 or higher)

So I try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ghc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ghc : Depends: libbsd-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This breaks the package manager. So then I can't install the libraries that I'm using GHC to install via cabal.

So then I do `sudo apt-get install -f` and that fixes the package manager but I still cant install `libbsd0`, `libbsd-dev`, or `ghc`.

**UPDATE**

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy ghc libbsd-dev
ghc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.6.3-10
  Version table:
     7.6.3-10 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
libbsd-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.0-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.6.0-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

And my version:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

Is ghc a supported package or not?

It's in the package universe, so I thought it would be supported.

How can I install this supported package??

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `apt-cache policy ghc libbsd-dev` and `lsb_release -d` please? it seems to install OK for me on 14.04.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue which got resolved by downgrading my libbsd0.

```
sudo apt-get install libbsd0=0.6.0-2ubuntu1
```

My `libbsd0` was versioned `0.7.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` which is probably incompatible.